# Unable to execute cli magento commands

Tags: magento2, php, cli

```
An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig).
```

Above error appears on di compile, cache clean etc.

I am not sure why this error appearing.

Is their any fix for this?

Comment: Please provide more details. Have you installed new module or did any customization? Please revert and try.

Comment: Installed a module that have composer json with required 7.3 || 7.4 but my php version in system was 8

Comment: I have disabled the module & deleted composer.json file still error appears

Comment: Looks like error due to php version, its 8.0 & i am using magento 2.3.5-p1 so php version it should be 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was php version issue, magento 2.3.5-p1 requires 7.3 php version, in system it was 8.0.

Setting php version 7.3, solves the error.